# Swipe up/down gestures

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

Hey I need to Create Two Screens, One  Screen is Fixed with Tablayout and the other Screen is partially hide on  top of the screen.When i swipe down the layout it enlarges the full layout.Actually i am trying this task Using Vertical `viewpager` but it's a failure one.
This is a designing screen link 
https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/photo/118287572130604798559/6499719173766606962?authkey=CIWEzYL-3K3vHw

I am new to android and stackoverflow.i need your support for these task.I want some examples or reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BottomSheetDialog` for viewing of the content of the second layout.

Comment: @Nilu  BottomSheetDialog is hiding completely ,but i need my second layout is on the top of first layout in partially collapsed. if i press the arrow button it enlarges